# Instagram API for HTTPS callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using subscribe endpoint of [Instagram](https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions) and it gives me the following error message if my callback_url is HTTPS; it works fine if callback_url is HTTP; the error message:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "error_type": "APISubscriptionError",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "Invalid SSL certificate"
    }
}
```

PS: I saw this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/EjBO7D2Itow) saying "I think this because I checked the SSL certificate for api.instagram.com and it looks OK"; But I dont know where they exactly checked SSL certificate? I dont see this option in Instagram developer console...

Does this mean the callback_url cannot be HTTPS?

Any idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Callback URL is probably self-signed certificate. Instagram does not support self-signed certificates.

So you have to use HTTP or Get an SSL certificate for your website.

Also check this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/MaS4fjo8GXQ

> Hey folks,
>
> We've made a couple of changes recently that affected the realtime
>   API, and we wanted to update you all:
>
> 1) We centralized some of our error tracking, which made our previous
>   "blacklisting" rate limits too aggressive; we've identified this and
>   have raised these errors, resulting in fewer false positives
>
> 2) We
>   switched the library used for the POST requests, which had the
>   side-effect of starting to enforce proper SSL certificates. If you've
>   noticed a drop-off in realtime hooks, please double-check that your
>   certificate is valid on your host. Going forward, **this check will be
>   made when creating subscriptions, too, so incorrect subscriptions
>   won't be created.**
>
> 3) Finally, we've updated the documentation to
>   reflect that http://ec2-... URLs are often problematic (as we're on
>   Amazon and they will often resolve locally) and we instead recommend
>   using the public IP or an Elastic IP for that host.
>
> Thanks, Mike